# How to solve W/NetworkRequest: No App Check token for request?

Tags: firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

I cannot pass user info to firebase database, and I think this is the issue. My Authentication part works well, and can pass image to firebase storage. Can anyone explain to me what does this error mean?

[image]

Here is my method:

[image]

Also, in logcat, it shows "one way function results will be dropped but finished with status OK and parcel size 4", which I think is the same issue if I am not wrong

[image]

Here are my dependencies:

[image]

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please enter your code as text, not images. ([Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557))

Answer (score 4):

Searching elsewhere I found this answer:
"Seems like you have enabled App Check in your Firebase project. This feature was announced a few days ago, so it's unlikely you will find any info online. Check the docs to see if you have followed all the setup steps: https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check "

Comment: To give proper attribution, link to the source where you found this and credit the author

Answer (score 2):

The "No App Check token for request" error message indicates that your Firebase app has enabled App Check and that the security feature is blocking the request to upload a file to Firebase Storage.

Firebase App Check is a security feature that helps protect your Firebase resources from abuse, such as denial-of-service (DoS) attacks or fraudulent activities. It uses reCAPTCHA technology to verify the authenticity of requests coming from your app.

To fix the error message, you need to add App Check to your Flutter app and configure it to work with Firebase Storage. Here are the steps to do so:

1. Install the App Check package for Flutter by adding it to your **pubspec.yaml** file
   and running **flutter pub get**:

> dependencies:
> firebase_app_check: ^0.8.0

2. Configure App Check to work with Firebase Storage by adding the **firebase-storage** App Check extension to your Firebase project

> ```
> WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
>   await Firebase.initializeApp(
>     options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
>   );
>   await FirebaseAppCheck.instance.activate(
>     webRecaptchaSiteKey: 'recaptcha-v3-site-key',
>
>     androidProvider: AndroidProvider.debug,
>   );
> ```